# Valid checking, Raising an exception

Tags: python-3.x

The code I'm trying to write take a string in the format 'command arg1 arg2', Right now, I'm stuck and not sure how to write a valid command check, where the valid command is 'add' or 'sub' or 'mul' or 'div'. If the command is not a valid command, it raises InvalidCommand().

Here's my code:

```
class InvalidCommand(Exception):
    pass

def validate_input(string):
    """
    validate_input(str) -> (str, [float])

    If string is a valid command, return its name and arguments.
    If string is not a valid command, raise InvalidCommand

    Valid commands:
    add x y
    sub x y
    mul x y
    div x y

    Arguments x and y must be convertable to float.

    """

    li = []

    if len(string.split(' ')) != 3:
        raise InvalidCommand()
    else:
        try:
            float(string.split(' ')[1])
            float(string.split(' ')[2])
        except ValueError:
            raise InvalidCommand()

    x = float(string.split(' ')[1])
    y = float(string.split(' ')[2])
    li.append(x)
    li.append(y)
    z = (string.split(' ')[0], li)
    return z
```

Comment: You can just write an if-elif chain, checking for each of the four valid options, with a last else clause raising InvalidCommand.

Comment: If you want to get fancier, you create a list of valid arguments (`['add', 'sub', 'mul', 'div']`), and do `if arg in valid_args: ... else: raise InvalidCommand()`. This allows for an easier way to expand the number of valid arguments.

Comment: `if z[0] in ('add', 'sub', 'mul', 'div'):`

Comment: And finally, if you have specific actions (functions) to undertake for each valid argument, you can make a dict, with the valid arguments being the keys, and the values being the actions/function to call. You can then do `if arg in actions.keys(): action[key]() \n else: raise InvalidCommand()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can do bro

```
VA=['add', 'sub', 'mul', 'div']
string=string.split()
if string[0] not in VA:
    raise InvalidCommand()
elif len(string) !=3:
    raise InvalidCommand()
else:
    try:
        return (string[0],[float(string[1]),float(string[2])])
    except ValueError:
        raise InvalidCommand()
```